# Yii user module lastvisit_at not being set in db

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have a fresh install of yii webapp with the [yii user module](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/) installed, but the problem is that the 'lastvisit_at' db field is never being updated upon login. Its always set to the default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. I am using netbeans have searched the entire project looking for where this is set and i think i see the function but cannot get it to work. Im new to Yii and frameworks in general so im probably just overlooking something.

- Looks like the User.php array is setting the default value?
- I think the problem is in the lastVisit() function but im unsure what the problem is.

User.php

```
    public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.CConsoleApplication
    return ((get_class(Yii::app())=='CConsoleApplication' || (get_class(Yii::app())!='CConsoleApplication' && Yii::app()->getModule('user')->isAdmin()))?array(
        array('username', 'length', 'max'=>20, 'min' => 3,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect username (length between 3 and 20 characters).")),
        array('password', 'length', 'max'=>128, 'min' => 4,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect password (minimal length 4 symbols).")),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('username', 'unique', 'message' => UserModule::t("This user's name already exists.")),
        array('email', 'unique', 'message' => UserModule::t("This user's email address already exists.")),
        array('username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/u','message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect symbols (A-z0-9).")),
        array('status', 'in', 'range'=>array(self::STATUS_NOACTIVE,self::STATUS_ACTIVE,self::STATUS_BANNED)),
        array('superuser', 'in', 'range'=>array(0,1)),
                    array('create_at', 'default', 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'on' => 'insert'),
                    array('lastvisit_at', 'default', 'value' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'on' => 'insert'),
        array('username, password, email, superuser, status', 'required'),
        array('superuser, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('id, username, password, email, activkey, create_at, lastvisit_at, superuser, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    ):((Yii::app()->user->id==$this->id)?array(
        array('username, email', 'required'),
        array('username', 'length', 'max'=>20, 'min' => 3,'message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect username (length between 3 and 20 characters).")),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('username', 'unique', 'message' => UserModule::t("This user's name already exists.")),
        array('username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/u','message' => UserModule::t("Incorrect symbols (A-z0-9).")),
        array('email', 'unique', 'message' => UserModule::t("This user's email address already exists.")),
    ):array()));
}
```

LoginController.php

```
    public function actionLogin()
{
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $model=new UserLogin;
        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['UserLogin']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['UserLogin'];
            // validate user input and redirect to previous page if valid
            if($model->validate()) {
                $this->lastVisit();
                if (Yii::app()->user->returnUrl=='/index.php')
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
                else
                    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('/user/login',array('model'=>$model));
    } else
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnUrl);
}

private function lastVisit() {
    $lastVisit = User::model()->notsafe()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $lastVisit->lastvisit = time();
    $lastVisit->save();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure thet lastVisit function is well executed ? (try to put some log in it)

Answer (score 0):

In your lastVisit() function try change this

```
$lastVisit->lastvisit = time();
```

to this

```
$lastVisit->lastvisit_at = time();
```

Comment: I tried that and no change to the db entry upon login.

Comment: do you have any function in your User.php file? something like 'setLastvisit' ?? also as darkheir suggested try to find if lastVisit function in your controller is well executed

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured it out. When i implemented the Yii-user module i didn't replace the CMenu url for the login method. Once i swapped that out it worked as intended.